# Update Xcode version on hosted machines

Tags: azure-devops

I can see that my hosted build machine has Xcode 11.3 installed however Apple has since then released 11.4.x and 11.5

How do we go about asking Microsoft to updating the hosted build machines? They used to update the machines a few days after Apple released updates.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you were using [macOS X Mojave 10.14](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-10.14-Readme.md).  It's using Xcode 11.3.1 (default) in the image.

You should use [macOS X Catalina 10.15](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md) when you select the host agent.

[image]

It's using **Xcode 11.4.1 as default and als**o include 11.5 in the image.

If you have to use macOSX 10.14,  since that image do not include Xcode 11.4.x and 11.5, you may need to use a self-hosted agent that includes the exact versions of software that you need.